# How to solve Retrofit Android java.net.UnknownHostException: host == null on numeric domain

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit android latest versio 1.6 with OKhttp2.0.0-RC2 with Okio

[image]

When I call Post method this [Json generator URL](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bIuGoEszqW?indent=2) call the code works fine with status code 200 (i e it calls success(.. ) method, parses the json everything works fine!

Json:

```
{
    "responseCode": "200",
    "responseMessage": "OK",
    "responseDetail": {
        "surname": "Trevor",
        "forename": "Ross",
        "dob": "10101960",
        "appRefNo": "1258866",
        "result": "Success"
    }
}
```

Code:
String hostUrl=[image]

```
void doTrackRef(Map<String, String> paramsref2) {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(hosturl)
```

.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler()).build();

```
    TrackerRefRequest userref = restAdapter.create(TrackerRefRequest.class);
    userref.login(paramsref2,
            new Callback<TrackerRefResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void success(
                        TrackerRefResponse trackdetailresponse,
                        Response response) {

                    Toast.makeText(TrackerActivity.this, "Success",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {


                    Toast.makeText(TrackerActivity.this, "No internet",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            });
}
```

MyErrorHandler class:

```
class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
      @Override public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError cause) {
        Response r = cause.getResponse();
        if (r != null && r.getStatus() == 401) {
          return new Throwable(cause);
        }
        return cause;
      }
    }
```

}

Pojo:

```
public class TrackerRefResponse {

private String responseCode;

private String responseMessage;

private ResponseDetail responseDetail;

//Setters and Getters


}
```

The above code works 100% everything is fine.

**Problem:** 
When i change the Json url api to IP numbered numeric URL ex: [image]

I'm getting this error log:

```
 D/Retrofit(9114): ---> HTTP POST http://[IP-Address]/api/index.php/data/TrackerInfo
 D/Retrofit(9114): Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
 D/Retrofit(9114): Content-Length: 22
 D/Retrofit(9114): app_ref_no=E0000000001
 D/Retrofit(9114): ---> END HTTP (22-byte body)
 D/dalvikvm(9114): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 224K, 7% free 4667K/4996K, paused 2ms, total 4ms
D/Retrofit(9114): ---- ERROR http://[IP-Address]/api/index.php/data/TrackerInfo
D/Retrofit(9114): java.net.UnknownHostException: host == null
D/Retrofit(9114):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:231)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:317)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:420)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:105)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:239)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.prepareRequest(UrlConnectionClient.java:68)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:37)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
D/Retrofit(9114):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
D/Retrofit(9114): ---- END ERROR
```

Update:

This issue is solved by the accepted answer!

Comment: this is being analyzed on https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/951

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android's URI class doesn't like the extra `0` in the fourth octet of `192.168.100.06`. Replace it with the canonical IP address `192.168.100.6` and you're golden.

I reported [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72098) to the AOSP issue tracker. I'm not 100% sure they'll fix it; there's major drawbacks to using non-canonical hostnames.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works perfectly! I copied url from REST api documentation which is build by REST api back-end developer :)